# Issue Terraform to deploy azurerm_data_factory_managed_private_endpoint for a azure data factory with fqdns

Tags: azure, terraform, dns, azure-data-factory

I have an issue with the deployment of a azure data factory with a azurerm_data_factory_managed_private_endpoint, in this managed private endpoint I am setting the parameter fqdns:

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_managed_private_endpoint" "adfmpe" {
  count = var.adfmpe_name != null ? 1 : 0

  name               = "adfm_private_endpoint"
  data_factory_id    = azurerm_data_factory.adf.id
  target_resource_id = "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<rsg_name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storagetestadf"
  subresource_name   = "blob
  fqdns              = ["storagetestadf.blob.core.windows.net"]
}
```

and the error is:
Error: `fqdns` should not be specified for the target resource: "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<rsg_name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storagetestadf"

How I can fix it???

thanks

Comment: This is a known issue refer here- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/15640 > A workaround is to add ignore changes block - subresource_name   = "blob"
  lifecycle {
    # even if the folowing properties of the resource are not match with the template, it will not be updated. 
    ignore_changes = [
      fqdns,
    ]
  }
} as given in the comment [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/15640#issuecomment-1068803247)

Comment: I think that is not the same issue, in my case is when terraform apply, so I tried the solution of ignore_changes but the error is the same: `fqdns` should not be specified for the target resource:.......

Comment: Can you run this sample- with your parameters- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_managed_private_endpoint there's possibility your target resource Id is not correct also the terraform version should be 3.61.0

Comment: in the target resource id I am using the storage account id, is wrong???

Comment: Yes, And also recheck your fqdn once? -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview#dns-configuration

Comment: but in the example of https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_managed_private_endpoint the id of storage account is used as target_resource_id... I don't understand...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254101/discussion-between-siddheshdesai-and-daniel-vega-ruiz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [**Terraform**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_managed_private_endpoint) Document Target resource id is the ID of the Private Link resource. I used below code to deploy ADF with managed private endpoint, The managed Private endpoint was enabled successfully. But to add the Private Link resource and fqdn you need to create Private Link service along with ADF.

Private endpoint code referred from this [**SO thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736050/azure-private-endpoints-and-terraform)

My **main.tf** code:-

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.61.0"
    }
  }
}

features {
  resource_group {
    prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
  }
}

}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-silicon"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                            = "exa-siliconadf"
  location                        = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  managed_virtual_network_enabled = true
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "siliconexa-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                                           = "siliconstrg-exa-subnet"
  resource_group_name                            = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name                           = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes                                 = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  # enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = false
  # // enforce_private_link_service_network_policies = false
  # // service_endpoints                              = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
}  

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "examsilicon3"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
}
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "valley-endpoint65"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "valley-privatesconn"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
    subresource_names              = ["blob"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "valleydnsgrp5"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "valleylink.blob.core.windows.net"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "example" {
  name                  = "valley-dns45"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
}


resource "azurerm_data_factory_managed_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name               = "exam-siliconpre"
  data_factory_id    = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  target_resource_id = "Private-link-resource-id"
  fqdns = ["test.mysql.database.azure.com", "examsilicon3.blob.core.windows.net"]
  depends_on = [ azurerm_data_factory.example ]
}
```

I created Private Link resource by adding fqdn inside it with the code below, [**Reference**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/private_link_service) :-

**main.tf:-**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.61.0"
    }
  }
}

features {
  resource_group {
    prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
  }
}

}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "v-siliconrg5"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "v-vnet5"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  address_space       = ["10.5.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                                          = "v-subnet5"
  resource_group_name                           = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name                          = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes                              = ["10.5.1.0/24"]
  enforce_private_link_service_network_policies = true
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "v-siliconpubip"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {
  name                = "v-lbsilicon3"
  sku                 = "Standard"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = azurerm_public_ip.example.name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_link_service" "example" {
  name                = "ex-siliconps"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  auto_approval_subscription_ids              = ["00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"]
  visibility_subscription_ids                 = ["00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"]
  load_balancer_frontend_ip_configuration_ids = [azurerm_lb.example.frontend_ip_configuration.0.id]
  fqdns = ["examsilicon3.blob.core.windows.net", "bhargava.mysql.database.azure.com"]

  nat_ip_configuration {
    name                       = "primary"
    private_ip_address         = "10.5.1.17"
    private_ip_address_version = "IPv4"
    subnet_id                  = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    primary                    = true
  }

  nat_ip_configuration {
    name                       = "secondary"
    private_ip_address         = "10.5.1.18"
    private_ip_address_version = "IPv4"
    subnet_id                  = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    primary                    = false
  }

}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                            = "valleysiliconadf"
  location                        = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  managed_virtual_network_enabled = true
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "examsilicon78"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "example-endpoint"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "example-privateserviceconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "example-dns-zone-group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "privatelink.blob.core.windows.net"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "example" {
  name                  = "example-link"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
}


resource "azurerm_data_factory_managed_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name               = "esililiconpre"
  data_factory_id    = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  target_resource_id = azure-privatelink-resource-id
  fqdns = ["bhargava.mysql.database.azure.com", "examsilicon3.blob.core.windows.net"]
  depends_on = [ azurerm_data_factory.example ]
}
```

**Output:-**

Managed Private endpoint got enabled for the Datafactory:-

[image]

The Private Link Service expects, FQDN and target resource type as Private Link resource or its ID if entered manually, Refer below:-

[image]

Create private endpoint for storage account like below:-

[image]

[image]